# Windows Phone 8.0 Coded UI test

Tags: windows-phone-8, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

Hi I am having trouble creating a Coded UI Test for a Windows Phone 8.0 application and would be grateful for some help.

Environment: Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2013, and working with a Windows Phone App for Windows Phone 8.0.

1. I can start an emulator and deploy the application to the emulator.
2. I have added a new Coded UI Test project to the VS 2013 solution.
3. The Coded UI Test Builder is started.
4. I click the Start Recording button.
5. I click a button in the deployed application's UI, and see Click 'Input Capture Window' client displayed above the Coded UI Test Builder window.
6. I click the Pause Recording button.
7. I click the Generate Code button.

At this point, I hope and expect that code will be generated for this simple test without any problems.

Actually what happens is that an exception is displayed in a dialog box:

Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestException' in Assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension,Version 12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f1d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.

I have seen this problem occur on two different Windows 8.1 machines and have tried googling to see if there is a solution to this, but have not found anything so far.

Thanks for any help, Martin

Answer (score 1):

WP 8.0 automation is not supported by coded ui test. As per [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dd380742.aspx) only WinRT-XAML based phone apps (which were added in WP 8.1) are supported by coded ui test for phone.